# What type of tree was the Eitz haChaim (Tree of Life)?

Tags: genesis-bereishith

What type of tree was the Eitz haChaim (Tree of Life) spoken about in Bereishis 2:9?

> יַּצְמַ֞ח יְהוָ֤ה אֱלֹהִים֙ מִן־הָ֣אֲדָמָ֔ה כָּל־עֵ֛ץ נֶחְמָ֥ד לְמַרְאֶ֖ה וְט֣וֹב לְמַאֲכָ֑ל וְעֵ֤ץ הַֽחַיִּים֙ בְּת֣וֹךְ הַגָּ֔ן וְעֵ֕ץ הַדַּ֖עַת ט֥וֹב וָרָֽע׃
>
> And from the ground the LORD God caused to grow every tree that was pleasing to the sight and good for food, with the tree of life in the middle of the garden, and the tree of knowledge of good and bad.

It was a tree that Adam and Chava would have been able to eat from (if they had remained in Gan Eden), so that suggests a fruit tree of some kind.  Chazal discuss what kind of tree the Eitz HaDaat was; do they also discuss this one?  What do they say about it?

Comment: The Eitz HaDaas has already been eaten so it wouldn't be a problem if it's available now. On the other hand there's strong reason to suspect no currently known tree is the Eitz haChaim. So just because Chazal discuss the Eitz HaDaas doesn't mean they'd discuss the Eitz haChaim about which it would be much harder to say anything.

Comment: https://www.jewishlinknj.com/features/16154-was-the-forbidden-fruit-in-gan-eden-an-apple

Comment: @rosends That article is about the eitz hadaas, I am asking about the eitz hachaim.

Comment: In a discussion that I had with a friend many years ago, I proposed that the "Etz Hachaim" was a metaphor for the Torah. (See the verse in Mishlei or in your favorite siddur - your choice.) Of course, the problem with this definition is that it would seem that the Torah would forbid itself.

Comment: According to Midrash B'reishit Rabbati (B'reshit pg. 23) it was a very large tree: 
ועץ החיים בתוך הגן, ונופו מכסה על כל עדן ויש בו ח' מאות מיני טעמים. מדת עץ החיים כנגד כל הישוב שנאמר [ו]עץ החיים, עץ שהוא על פני כל החיים

Comment: Note that it could be a particular tree (of the same type as others) that was designated in Gan Aiden to be unlike all others of that type. As a result, we cannot know anything about what it was and what it was like.

Comment: The whole point of being kicked out of Gan Eden was so that they couldn't eat the fruit of the tree of life. So it wouldn't really make sense that the fruit is freely available outside of Gan Eden. For me the only tree of life available is the Torah.

Comment: @DanF the Zohar explains that the Etz Hadaat is revealed Torah (the halachic debates of issur v heter) and the Etz Hachaim is the hidden Torah.

Comment: I don't recall where but I remember learning something which said the eitz hachaim didn't have any obvious fruit but that it's bark was edible where as the eitz hadass that chava saw was good to eat was bearing fruits that were obvious to the eye.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I do not think there are sources that exactly describe what the etz hachayim was. There are several discussions in the Gemara on what the Etz HaDaas was, but see the list below. It does not completely answer your question, but if someone can add to this list, be welcome!

### The looks

So first of all, according to the Chibbah Yeteirah on this posuk, the tree of life, ועץ החיים, was not a pretty tree to look at at all. He writes:

> כל עץ נחמד למראה וטוב למאכל ועץ החיים. עץ החיים לא היה נחמד למראה וטוב למאכל כשאר העצים, ולכן האדם ואשתו לא אכלו ממנו. ובמשלי (ג) נמשלה התורה לעץ חיים כיון שהוא עץ צנוע בלי תאוה לעינים אבל מביא לחיי עולם, ודומה לתורה כמו שאמרו באבות (ו) כך היא דרכה של תורה פת במלח תאכל וכו'.

This idea is echoed by the [Kli Yakar](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Kli%20Yakar&lang2=en):

> The Tree of Life. Hashem did not command Adam to refrain from eating of this tree because it bore no seductive fruit. Rather it was the tree itself that granted immortality. By contrast the fruit of the Tree of Knowledge was extremely tempting and after they had eaten of it they understood the benefit to be had by partaking of the Tree of Life as well.

### Did it have fruits?

According to the [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Radak&lang2=en), all the trees in Gan Eden were "fruit-bearing" trees, as implied by the words טוב למאכל in Bereishis 3:6

However, the Tur HaArokh cites R' Rabbi Joseph Kimchi in his commentary and says something interesting:

> Rabbi Joseph Kimchi explains that the tree of knowledge and the tree
> of life were one and the same tree.

### The size of the tree

Not very much is known about the etz hachayim. But, the Midrash ([Bereishis Rabbah 15:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.15.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) mentions a teaching from Rabbi Yehudah Bar Ela'ayi which says that the tree was pretty big, extending for the journey of five hundred years. The Etz Yosef explains that the deeper meaning behind this is that the tree was growing and growing, as to serve as a shield before men, and guide them so to speak (see also: Matnot Kehunah). According to the [Yefeh To'ar](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.15.6?lang=bi&with=Yefeh%20To%27ar&lang2=en), the whole concept of the etz hachayim is that it refers to the Torah.

### How many fruits did it have?

In [Pri Etz Hadar](https://www.sefaria.org/Pri_Etz_Hadar.4.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), from the teachings of the Ari HaKadosh, it is written that the etz hachayim, the tree of life, had 12 (different?) fruits:

> Wherever all thirty of the fruits mentioned above, whose roots are in the worlds of Creation, Formation, and Making, can be found, it is a mitzvah to obtain them. For whoever does much is surely worthy of praise. However, wherever they are not all available, there should be no less than twelve types of fruit, corresponding to the fruit of the supernal tree, the Tree of Life. It is established as a Holy Tree in twelve directions, the secret of the twelve permutations of the Name, YHVH. For each of these the kavvanah should be one of the twelve permutations, according to the order mentioned above .

Answer (score 0):

It's much more supernal than an earthy tree, as is everything there in Bereishit, all lofty things and Chokhmah and Torah. Yes Chazal discuss Etz HaChayim (abbreviated EH here).

Rashbi's sefer, Tikunei Zohar has 41 occurrences of EH. There, it's generally the Amuda Emtzaita (Central Column, Pillar), an attribute of H"Y that unites all the worlds, like the Waw that unites His Name. However the Intro (daf 2b)  mentions that the Lulab represents Tzaddik (and the three Hadassim the Avot, two Aravot the two Prophets of Truth, and Etrog - Shekhina), so as far as earthly trees go that's probably the strongest association and model.

The 41 occurences are listed below, and some are translated. They describe, illustrate, and differentiate EH from Etz haDaat T"W and also Kol-Etz.

---

Tikunei Zohar
41 occurences of "**עץ החיים**"

(Shiluach haKan:) B'khol-etz (Deut. 22:6) – this is EH, of which it says (Prov. 3:18) "Etz Chayyim (no Hei) is she (Chokhmah) to those who hold onto her" and of her it's said, "For man is the tree of the field." Another thing: bkhol-etz is Tzaddik which is Etz Pri osseh Pri l'mino which is Yom Shabbat, which there, is the Ziwwug of the Shekhina and K"BH, and there she (he) has contentment, and of her it's said, "And he shall be as a Tree planted by the rivulets of water which gives its fruit in its time" – this is the time of the Tzaddik which is Shabbat night, as from Tzaddik fly out new Neshamot in Yisrael erev Shabbat which are caled Panim Chadashot.

בכל עץ דא איהו **עץ החיים**, דאתמר ביה עץ חיים היא למחזיקים בה, ועליה אתמר כי האדם עץ השדה, ועוד בכל עץ דא צדיק דאיהו עץ פרי עשה פרי למינו, ודא יום השבת דתמן זווגא דשכינתא עם קודשא בריך הוא, ותמן אית לה (נ"א ליה) נייחא, ועליה אתמר והיה כעץ שתול על פלגי מים אשר פריו יתן בעתו, דא עתו דצדיק דאיהי ליל שבת, דצדיק מניה פרחין נשמתין חדתין בישראל ערב שבת דאתקריאו (נ"א על שם דא איתקריאו) פנים חדשות:

EH, its buds are Sam haChayim, the spice of Life.

דדא איהו **עץ החיים**, דאיבא דיליה סם חיים בת זוגיה, נטירא ליה בעלמא דין ובעלמא דאתי, עלה אתמר ולקח גם מ**עץ החיים** ואכל וחי לעולם, גם לרבות בת זוגיה, סם חיים דיליה, ואיהו נטיר ליה בעלמא דין ובעלמא דאתי, ומאן דבעי לנטלא בת זוגיה, כגון אוריה דאקדים לדוד, אתמר ביה כל אוכליו יאשמו רעה תבא אליהם נאם ה':

EH is the Amuda Emtzaita, the Central Column, the W' in Hashem, that unites it all.

כד אינון באבא ובאימא, לימינא ושמאלא, כל חד איהו שם בפני עצמו, וכד אינון בכתר עליון אינון ביחודא חדא, כגוונא דא יאקקויק"ק, בחסד וגבורה אינון יקו"ק אקי"ק, ענפין מתפרדין לימינא ושמאלא, בעמודא דאמצעיתא אינון תרוייהו ביחודא חדא, והכי אינון ענפין מתפרדין בנצח והוד, יקו"ק לימינא אקי"ק לשמאלא, בצדיק מתייחדים, הא הכא רזא דאילנא, דאתפשטן ענפוי מעילא, ומתייחדין בשרשוי לתתא, ודא **עץ החיים**:

It's Etz Ha-Chayim with a Hei having to do with the five (gevurot) embodied in the first Hei.

דאיהי י' דנפיק מגו אוירא דכיא, דאיהו כתר עלאה, ובגין דאלין חמש מדידין אינון ברזא דה' עלאה, איהו אזיל בהון חמש מאה שנין בין כל חד וחד, ורזא דמלה **עץ החיים** מהלך חמש מאות שנה, ובין כל חד וחד חמש מאות שנה, ובעובי דכל חד וחד חמש מאות שנה, דכלהו סלקין במתקלא דחמש חמש לכל סטרא:

EH was cast by Moshe into the bitter waters which were sweetend by it. It was created on that Spring which is the Shekhinah.

והכי הוו ישראל עד דאחזי לון עץ, הדא הוא דכתיב (שם ט"ו) ויורהו ה' עץ וישלך אל המים וימתקו המים, ודא **עץ החיים**, דאתרבי על ההוא מבועא דאיהי שכינתא, י' מבועא דאשקי לאילנא דאיהו ו', והאי עץ מהלך חמש מאות שנה דאינון ה', וימתקו המים דא ה' בתראה, דאתמר בה קראן לי מרה, דשכינתא תתאה איהי מעין גנים דלית ליה פסק, טפה דאתמשכא מן מוחא, וכמה טפין אתמשכאן מניה, דאינון בתולת אחריה רעותיה:

EH is W'. Ha-Chayim are Aba and Ima which are Y"H. And it "goes five hundreed years" which is the final Hei.

דבר אחר שימני כחותם על לבך, האי קרא על שכינתא אתמר דאיהי בגלותא, חותם לא כתיב, אלא כחותם, כההוא חותם דגושפנקא דאיהי חותם אמת, ובה (נ"א ודא) חתמנו לחיים, ומאי ניהו האי חותם דבה חיים, אלא דא **עץ החיים**, דביה בני חיי ומזוני נפקין, עץ ודאי ההוא דאתמר ביה **עץ החיים** מהלך ת"ק שנה, והאי עץ איהי ו', מהלך ת"ק שנין דא ה', החיים אינון אבא ואימא דאינון י"ק, י' איהו חכמה, ומנלן דאתקרי חיים, כמה דאת אמר והחכמה תחיה בעליה, ה' ביה אימא עלאה, מנא לן דאתקרי חיים, כמה דאת אמר עץ חיים היא ודאי, ותרוייהו כי חיים הם למוצאיהם:

EH is the W' in the middle of the Alef that unites between the Mayim and Mayim, and one eats from it and lives forever.

בודאי אבני שיש טהור אינון י' י', דמנהון מיין דכיין נפקין, ואינון רמיזין באת א' רישא וסופא י' י', ו' דאיהו נטוי בינייהו איהו עץ חיים, מאן דאכל מניה וחי לעולם, ואלין תרין יודי"ן אינון רמיזין בוייצר, ואינון תרין יצירות יצירה דעלאין ויצירה דתתאין, ואינון חכמה בראש וחכמה בסוף, תעלומות חכמה, ודאי אינון תעלומות מחכמה עלאה (דאיהו) דתחות כתר עלאה. (נ"א קם סבא דסבין עתיקא דעתיקין, ואמר רבי רבי מאי ניהו דאמר רבי עקיבא לתלמידוי כשתגיעו לאבני שיש טהור אל תאמרו מים מים שמא תסכנו בעצמיכם, הדא הוא דכתיב דובר שקרים לא יכון לנגד עיני, הא כתיב יהי רקיע בתוך המים ויהי מבדיל בין מים למים, ועוד מים עליונים ומים תחתונים אית תמן, למה אמר אל תאמרו מים מים, אמר ליה בוצינא קדישא, סבא דסבין לך יאות לגלאה רזא דא, דלית חבריא יכלין לקיימא לה על בורייה, אמר ליה סבא דסבין, רבי רבי בוצינא קדישא, בודאי אבני שיש טהור אינון י' י', דאינון חד יו"ד עלאה מן א', ותניינא יו"ד תתאה מינה, והכא לית טומאה אלא אבני שיש טהור, ולית הפרשה בין מים למים, דכולא יחודא חדא, דאלין אינון מסטרא דאילנא דחיי דאיהו ו' באמצעיתא דא', דאתמר ביה ולקח גם מ**עץ החיים** ואכל וחי לעולם, אבל אילנא דעץ הדעת לתתא):

R' Akiba told his students: When you get to Avei Shayish Tahor don't say Mayim Mayim: don't equate Avnei Shayish Tahor to other stones, as they're Life and Death, as there the wise man's heart is to his right and the fool's to his left.
Furthermore you'd endanger your lives, since these stones of Etz haDaat T"W are discreet, and these Avnei Shayish Tahor are in inseparable unity.
And if you say since the EH was taken from them and they fell there's separation between them - "He that speaks likes will not remain before my eyes," for behold in that place there's no separation up on high, and these that were created are from those.

ויהיב לון אחרנין מסטרא דעץ הדעת טוב ורע, דמתמן אתייהיבת אורייתא באסור והתר, מימינא חיי ומשמאלא מיתה, ובגין דא אמר רבי עקיבא לתלמידוי כשתגיעו לאבני שיש טהור אל תאמרו מים מים, ולא תהוון שקילין אבני שיש טהור לאבנים אחרנין, דאינון חיי ומיתה, דתמן לב חכם לימינו דבר נש, ולב כסיל לשמאלו, ולא עוד אלא אתם תסכנו עצמכם, בגין דאלין אבנין דעץ הדעת טוב ורע אינון בפרודא, ואלין אבני שיש טהור אינון ביחודא בלא פרודא כלל, ואם תאמרו דהא אסתליק **עץ החיים** מנייהו ונפלו ואית פרודא בינייהו, דובר שקרים לא יכון לנגד עיני, דהא לית תמן פרודא לעילא, ואלין דאתברו מאינון (מאנין) הוו, אתו לנשקא ליה פרח ואסתלק מנייהו:

"Every tree desirable to the sight and good to eat" – is Tzaddik.
"To the sight" is the Shekhinah, of which it sais, "in a vision I will make Myself known to him."
EH is the Central Pillar, as it's the supernal EH of which it says "Ha-chokhmah, the wisdom, gives life to her owner."

אמר ליה רבי יהודה, והא כל עץ כתיב, אי הוה אמר עץ שפיר, אבל כל עץ כתיב, אמר ליה ודאי הכי הוא, דבכל אתר כ"ל צדיק איהו, אבל כלא חד, כל דא צדיק, עץ דא עמודא דאמצעיתא, דגוף וברית חשבינן חד, אבל בהאי קרא כל עץ נחמד למראה וטוב למאכל דא צדיק, למראה דא שכינתא דאתמר בה במראה אליו אתודע, ו**עץ החיים** דא עמודא דאמצעיתא, דאיהו **עץ החיים** דלעילא דאתמר בה החכמה תחיה בעליה:

The Lower Shekhinah is Gan, garden, from which the EH is planted, as it says "EH in the midst of the Gan."
So what is "from the Adamah?" - now that's the Upper Shekhinah, as from it is planted Kol-Etz which is Tzaddik, K"L from the side of M"Y, as they're same gematria, and on account of her it says (Job. 38:29), "From the belly of MY, who, came forth the Kerach, ice" etc. which is "the awesome crystal" (Eze. 1:22).

אמר ליה הא שכינתא תתאה איהי גן, דמתמן **עץ החיים** נטוע, כמה דאתמר ו**עץ החיים** בתוך הגן, מאי מן האדמה, אלא דא שכינתא עלאה, דמינה אתנטע כל עץ דאיהו צדיק, כ"ל איהו מסטרא דמ"י, דהכי סליק לחשבן כ"ל מ"י, ובגינה אתמר מבטן מי יצא הקרח וגומר, דאיהו הקרח הנורא:

The heavens - is EH. The earth – is "all tree desireable to the sight."
"And the earth was astonishlingly chaotic" – is Etz haDaat T"W…

בראשית ברא אלקי"ם, את השמים **עץ החיים**, ואת הארץ כל עץ נחמד למראה. והארץ היתה תהו ובהו דא עץ הדעת טוב ורע, ודא רזא תהו עמק רע, בהו עמק טוב, ודא עץ הדעת טוב ורע, כי שם בלל ה' שפת כל הארץ, ומהכא נפק כל ערבוביא דטוב ורע, דאיהו רזא דצדיק ורע לו רשע וטוב לו:

(Creation of man) … behold it's the scripture (Ex. 26) "And they shall be twins below and together united innocent up to his head" – where? - "to the ring." This is the ring of the Berit Mila, which is temptest for all urges below, but tempest for unity above. And above it's said of it "and take from EH and eat and live forever" but below it's said of it "and of the Etz haDaat T"W don't eat of it" – don't mix in unity Tov and Ra, and if not then "die – you will die." It says here Mot Tamut and it says of Shabbat "those that desecrate her Mot Yumat."

ותא חזי בשעתא דבעא קודשא בריך הוא למברי אדם, הכי הוה בעי למעבד ליה כגוונא דדיוקנא דיליה, בלא ערוה ובלא פרץ ופירוד, כמה דאת אמר נעשה אדם בצלמנו כדמותנו, למהוי כל ספירן כלילן ביה, בלא פרוד וקצוץ, ולאתייחדא בן עם בת דאינון אחים, דעלייהו אתמר אחים תאומים, הדא הוא דכתיב (שמות כ"ו) ויהיו תואמים מלמטה ויחדיו יהיו תמים על ראשו, באן אתר, אל הטבעת, דא טבעת דאות ברית מילה, דאיהו שעור לכל עריין לתתא, ושעור דיחודא לעילא, ולעילא אתמר ביה ולקח גם מ**עץ החיים** ואכל וחי לעולם, אבל לתתא אתמר ביה ומעץ הדעת טוב ורע לא תאכל ממנו, לא תערב ביחודא טוב עם רע, ואם לאו מות תמות, אתמר הכא מות תמות ואתמר בשבת מחלליה מות יומת:

The rest of the occurences:

```
כמה דגרים אדם דשכינתא אתפרשת מקודשא בריך הוא, כמה דאת אמר ובפשעיכם שלחה אמכם, ואשתאר קודשא בריך הוא יחידאי בלא מטרוניתא, הדא הוא דכתיב (ישעיה נ"ז) הצדיק אבד, מאי אבד, אבד למטרוניתא, ובגין דא לא טוב היות האדם לבדו אעשה לו עזר כנגדו, דא אחרא, דלית איהי בת זוגיה, מסטרא דעץ הדעת טוב ורע, באסור והיתר טומאה וטהרה כשר ופסול דם טהור ודם נדה, ובגין דא אוקמוהו זכה נעשה לו עזר, לא זכה כנגדו, דאסתלק מניה אתתא דאיהי **עץ החיים**, דאתמר בה עץ חיים היא למחזיקים בה, ראה חיים עם אשה אשר אהבת, דעלה אתמר ולקח גם מ**עץ החיים** ואכל וחי לעולם, דאיהו הוה חרות על הלוחות, חירו ממלאך המות, חירו משעבוד מלכיות, חירו מכל מרעין בישין, מעניותא וטפשותא וצערא ודוחקא וכפנא, ועלה אתמר ארץ אשר לא במסכנות תאכל בה לחם וכו':

בראשית דא ברי"ת, דאתמר ביה **עץ החיים**, והא אוקמוה, ובהפוכא תבי"ר, דגרים תבירו לאדם הראשון, ודא עץ הדעת טוב ורע, טוב איהו אילנא, ההוא דכתיב ותרא האשה כי טוב העץ למאכל וכי תאוה הוא לעינים, ואיבא דיליה רע, כפום חיזו דיליה הכי הוה (נ"א איהו) אתחזיא לה מלבר, כגוונא דפימא מלין שפירין מלבר, ולבא מליא טנופין מלגאו, ודא לא הות ידעא דסם המות הוה מלגאו דאיבא, הדא הוא דכתיב ותקח מ"פריו ו"תאכל, ותתן גם לאישה וגומר, הרי איבא דאילנא דתמן מו"ת (מלגאו גרים לה דאכלה):

ועוד וישמעו את קול ה' אלקי"ם, ההוא קלא הוה בגנתא דאיהי שכינתא, דתמן **עץ החיים** נטוע, חוה גרמת דאתעקר אילנא מגנתא, ואדם גרים במחשבתא דיליה דאסתליק נביעו דאילנא, דהוה נחית לגנתא, ואשתארת יבשה, יקו"ק דא אילנא, ה"ה ענפוי ושרשוי, ו' גופא דאילנא, י' איבא דיליה, נביעו דיליה, נקודה דיליה כגוונא דא יהוה, דאיהו אחד ושמו אחד, ומנלן דאתקרי נביעו אחד, כמה דאתמר יקוו המים מתחת השמים אל מקום אחד, ותראה היבשה אדנ"י:

אלא בגין דאתמר בה ויצמח ה' אלקי"ם מן האדמה כל עץ נחמד למראה וטוב למאכל ו**עץ החיים** בתוך הגן ועץ הדעת טוב ורע, והוה ליה רשו לממחא בידא דאדם דלא ייכול מאילנא דמותא, ולא מחאת, בגין דא אמר בעבורך. אמר ליה רבי אלעזר, וכי אית דעת בארעא לכולי האי, אמר ליה אין, הדא הוא דכתיב (משלי ג') ה' בחכמה יסד ארץ, אמר ליה והא בחכמה עלאה ובארעא דקודשא בריך הוא אתמר האי קרא, אמר ליה ברי דא לקבל דא עבד קודשא בריך הוא, אית חכמה ואית חכמה, אית ארעא ואית ארעא:

אמר ליה רבי אלעזר, וכי תרין נשין הוו ליה, אמר ליה אין, חד יצר הטוב וחד יצר הרע, חדא מסטרא דעצם תקיפא דינא קשיא, וחדא מסטרא דבשרא, מתמן אינון רכיכי לבא, ואינון דגרמא אינון קשי קדל, ועל אתתא דאתנטילת מגרמא אמר בן סירא, גרמא דנפיל בחולקך טב או ביש גרריה, ועל אתתא דגרמא אמר אדם האשה אשר נתת עמדי, לא קרא לה אתתיה, כגוונא דחוה דאתמר בה ויקרא האדם שם אשתו חוה, דאחרא שפחה הות דמסטרא דעץ הדעת טוב ורע, חדא רע וחדא טוב, ומסטרא ד**עץ החיים** תרוייהו חיים:

ועתה פן ישלח ידו דא י', אם זכה ולקח גם מ**עץ החיים** דא ו' (נ"א ה'), ואכל וחי לעולם דא ו', חי ודאי, כד ה' הות יחידא מניה עאלת בין טוב לרע, הדא הוא דכתיב וייצר ה' אלקי"ם את האדם תרין יצירות טוב ורע, למנדע (ואתמר בהון ויפח באפיו נשמת חיים ודא ה' לדעת טוב ורע למנדע) מה דהוו גרמין למעבד, ובגין דא אעלת בינייהו:

בתר דחאב אדם דיצירה, אתפרשת ה' עלאה ואסתלקת מניה, ובגין דלא אתחזרת לגביה, אמר אם זכה ולקח גם מ**עץ החיים** ואכל וחי לעולם, והאי **עץ החיים** הוה נטוע בעץ הגן, ובגין דלא זכה למיכל מניה, מה כתיב ביה וישלחהו ה' אלקי"ם מגן עדן לעבוד את האדמה אשר לקח משם, ההוא דאתמר ביה וייצר ה' אלקי"ם את האדם עפר מן האדמה דלא הוה כדאי למהוי בגנתא דאורייתא, כיון דלא נטיר בה עץ הדעת טוב ורע באסור והתר, ועבר על מימרא דמאריה, דאם הוה נטיר דלא עבר על מימרא דמאריה, ולקח גם מ**עץ החיים** דאתמר בה תורת חכם מקור חיים לסור ממוקשי מות, עץ חיים היא למחזיקים בה, ודא איהו ולקח גם מ**עץ החיים** ואכל וחי לעולם, גם לרבות נוקבא, איבא דאילנא פרי צדיק:

ועוד הן האדם היה כאחד ממנו, אמרו מלאכין קדישין בגין למהוי איהו כאחד מיננא כמה דאמר חויא והייתם כאלקי"ם יודעי טוב ורע, ודא איהו לדעת טוב ורע, דא גרים ליה מותא, דאם זכה למיכל מאילנא דחיי דאיהו עץ חיים היא למחזיקים בה, מה כתיב בה ולקח גם מ**עץ החיים** וגומר:

אמר רבי שמעון ווי לון לאינון דמניחין לאשתדלא באורייתא דאתמר בה ולקח גם מ**עץ החיים**, ובפקודין דילה דאינון איבא דאילנא דאתמר ביה ואכל וחי לעולם, ואזלין בתר אלין דמפתי לון מסטרא דנחש הקדמוני, דאמרי לון השתדלון במלאכיא דממנן על ככביא ושמשא וסיהרא, ועל אלין דממנן על רוחין ושדין, למיהוי כאלקי"ם יודעי טוב ורע, ועלייהו:

אבל אלין דידעין אילנא דקודשא בריך הוא דאיהו **עץ החיים**, נטוע בגן דיליה דאיהי שכינתא דיליה, דאתמר בה לא יגורך רע, יכלין לנחתא חילא מתמן לגבי שכינתיה בלא ערבוביא כלל, בכל פקודא ופקודא, איהו עץ פרי עושה פרי למינו, נטוע בגן בלא ערבוביא כלל, ובגין דא אמר למינו, אבל עץ הדעת טוב ורע לא אתמר ביה למינו, אבל מעורב מין דלא במיניה, ובגיניה אתמר שדך לא תזרע כלאים וכו', שעטנז לא יעלה עליך:

בראשית ברא אלקי"ם, מאי אלקי"ם, להט החרב המתהפכת לשמור את דרך **עץ החיים**, מטה האלקי"ם ודאי, ודא מטטרו"ן, והא אוקימנא ליה דאתהפך מדינא לרחמי, וביה אשתניו (נ"א אשתכחו) כל דיוקנין דלא דמו דא לדא, כד אתהפך מימינא לשמאלא אחזי פרצופא דשור, וכד אתהפך משמאלא לימינא אחזי פרצופא דאריה, וכד אתהפך מתרווייהו למערב אחזיר אנפוי ואתהפך לנשר (נ"א לאדם), וכד אתהפך מתרוייהו למזרח דאיהו באמצעיתא אתהפך לאדם (נ"א לנשר), מלמטה לנשר, לית דיוקנא בעלמא דלא אשתמודע ביה:

איהו ערוה דאפריש בין ו"ה דאינון אח ואחות, כד אתלבש אילנא דחיי באילנא דטוב ורע, הדא הוא דכתיב ו**עץ החיים** בתוך הגן, ועץ הדעת טוב ורע, בזמנא דאיהי (ס"א דהאי) ער בין ברא וברתא לא תקרבו לגלות ערוה, לא תקרבו ו' לה' דלא אתגליא רע בינייהו דאיהו אחר, דעליה אתמר וסוד אחר אל תגל, ערי"ה תעור קשתך, ער יה רע, בזמנא דאיהו בין י"ה ההוא רע לא תקרב י' בה':

(עד דנטע ליה בארעא דישראל, וארכיב ליה בתלת אבהן ואצלח תמן, ובגין דא הן כל אלה יפעל א"ל פעמים שלש עם גבר, מיד דאצלח תמן ואחיד תמן, אתפשטו שרשוי על ארעא דאיהי שכינתא, ואסתלקו ענפוי בכל רקיעין, ובכל מרכבין, דנשמתין ומלאכיא וחיוון ושרפים ואופנים, עד דאתחזר כקדמיתא (ס"א עד אין סוף), והא אוקמוה **עץ החיים** מהלך ת"ק שנה, רבא אילנא ותקיף ורומיה ימטי לשמיא, וחזותיה לסוף כל ארעא, תחותוהי תטלל כל חיות ברא, ובענפוהי ידורון צפרי שמיא, דאינון נשמתין קדישין, ומניה יתזן כל בשרא):

ה' תתאה שרשא דאילנא, דאית ביה תלת ווי"ן לקבל תלת ענפין דש', ה' עלאה תלת ענפין, ואינון תלת ווי"ן מן ויסע ויבא ויט, האי איהו **עץ החיים** דאעקר ענפוי דקצץ בנטיעות ואסתלק איבא, ואתמר באילנא גדו אילנא וקצצו ענפוהי וכו', ברם עקר שרשוהי בארעא שבקו, דאיהו ה' תתאה, אסתלק הו"י ואשתאר ה', ובגין דא שלש משמרות הו"י הלילה, ובכל משמר ומשמר יושב הקדוש ברוך הוא ושואג כארי וכו', ה' דהלילה עלה קודשא בריך הוא שואג בשלש משמרות דתמן הו"י, תמן הו"י איהו ודאי:

ב' בתוספת, תרין כיסות פומא ולבא, דהכי אוקמוהו מארי מתניתין עלייהו, מי שאין תוכו כברו אל יכנס לבית המדרש, דודאי איהו מאילנא דטוב ורע, דאיהו יימא חד בלב וחד בפה, מאן דאיהו מאילנא דחיי איהו תוכו כברו, פומא ולבא שוים, ועלייהו אתמר ולקח גם מ**עץ החיים** ואכל וחי לעולם, אבל אחרא דאין תוכו כברו דלאו פומיה ולביה שוין, עליה אתמר ומעץ הדעת טוב ורע לא תאכל ממנו, דודאי דא איהו ערבוביא בישא, דמשקר מוניטא דמלכא, דמערב כספא בעופרת. ודא הוה חטא דחוה דהטיל בה נחש זוהמא, דאיהו עופרת דאתערב בטפה (נ"א בכספא) חוורא כספא מזוקק, ולא אתדכי זוהמא מניה עד דאתא אברהם ועאל בנורא ואתלבן כספא, ונפיק עופרת לבר דאיהו ישמעאל, ואתמר באדם מושך בערלתו הוה, אתערב ערבוביא בדהבא, אצטריף ביצחק, ואפיק זוהמא לבר ודא עשו, ביעקב נח ואשתרש ואפיק תולדין, ואתרבי **עץ החיים** בענפוי ושרשוי:

דינא קדמאה חדא אתקרי דין לדון בחנק, ואתמר (דברים כ"א) לא תלין נבלתו על העץ. אמר ליה אלעזר ברי, הכא צריך לחדשא מילין, אית עץ ואית עץ, הדא הוא דכתיב (שם כ') כי האדם עץ השדה, ואית אדם דאיהו עץ הדעת טוב ורע, וחובא דאדם איהי נבלתו דאדם קדמאה דאיהו **עץ החיים**, לא צריך לתליא ביה חובא דא, הדא הוא דכתיב לא תלין נבלתו על העץ, דמאן דאכל מעץ דיליה דאיהו **עץ החיים**, אתמר ביה ואכל וחי לעולם:

ועוד לא תלין נבלתו על העץ, עץ דהכא דא תלמיד חכם דאשתדל באורייתא דאיהי **עץ החיים**, הדא הוא דכתיב (משלי ג') עץ חיים היא למחזיקים בה, לא תלין בו נבלתו, דאיהי חובה דחב ביומא לא תלין עמיה בלילה, דמיד יתוב בתיובתא, כמה דאוקמוה מארי מתניתין אם ראית תלמיד חכם שחטא ביום אל תהרהר אחריו בלילה, דודאי עשה תשובה, (נ"א שמא עשה תשובה, שמא ס"ד, אלא אימא ודאי עשה תשובה):

דבר אחר לא תלין נבלתו על העץ, דא שבת, דירית ביה בר נש נשמתא יתירה, לא צריך לאתחזיא קדמהא נפשא דשלטא בבר נש ביומין דחול, במלאכה דאיהי אסורה בשבת, אלא קבור תקברנו ביום ההוא, דלא אתחזיא קדם זכור ושמור דשבת, ובגינה אתמר של נעליך מעל רגליך כי המקום אשר אתה עומד עליו אדמת קדש הוא, ולא תטמא את אדמתך, דנשמתא יתירה איהי ארץ ישראל דלעילא, אדמת קדש, דאתמר בה קדש ישראל לה'. ועוד לא תלין נבלתו על העץ דא בר נש דאיהו נבל, עליה אתמר כל המעמיד תלמיד דלאו איהו הגון כאלו מעמיד אשרה, ובגין דא לא תלין נבלתו על העץ דאיהו **עץ החיים**. דבר אחר לא תלין וגומר, העץ אלין ישראל דאתמר בהו:

דאיהי מתקשטא בכל מיני תכשיטין, ירושלם דאיהו צואר עלמא, קודשא בריך הוא אסחר לה, הדא הוא דכתיב (זכריה ה') ואני אהיה לה נאם ה' חומת אש סביב, ואיהו מחבק לה בתרין דרועין, הדא הוא דכתיב (שיר השירים ב') שמאלו תחת לראשי וימינו תחבקני. וידין דמטרוניתא כלה קדישא, אינון רשימין כלהו בשמא דיקו"ק, כגוונא דא (אמר המגיה הלשון מוטעה ונ"ל שהלשון כך) בכף י', בחמש אצבעאן ה', בדרועא דילה ו', בכתף דילה ה', בכף דילה מצויירין כמה שרטוטין כענפין דאילנא דחיי, לרשמא ביה דאיהו **עץ החיים**, הדא הוא דכתיב (משלי ג') עץ חיים היא למחזיקים בה ותמכיה מאשר, מימינא דיליה אתייהיבת אורייתא דבכתב, משמאלא דיליה אורייתא דבעל פה, ובאן אתייהיבו בתרין לוחין, דאתמר בהון שני שדיך כשני עפרים תאמי צביה:
```

---

Your question specified Chazal but for me it's clearer in this answer:
Per Prov. 11:30 **Etz haChayim is the Torah, which is the fruit of the Tzadiq.**
Per Likutei Moharan II, Hosafot Manuscript #5.
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/120825/11675

Answer (score -2):

In general, this is dealing with the subject of *the Garden* (**גן**) which G-d planted in the preceding posuk. Like the expression of the Sages, G-d looked into the Torah and created the universe. In keeping with that structure, there are 53 parshiyot to the Torah (ג״ן פרשיות לתורה) like is found in chapter 3 of Likut Amarim v'Pitgamei Kodesh.

Looking at the posuk you cite, there are several ideas that need to be noted.

First is that G-d caused *the whole of the tree* (כל-עץ) to sprout from the *earth* (האדמה). The expression of כל has a connotation of *the whole* or a wholistic perspective. It also has meaning of *enclosed* or *enwrapped*. That implies an external quality as is noted from the continuing comment *pleasant in appearance*. Appearance is the external aspect which is communicated to others.

The word *the earth* (**האדמה**) alludes to both the first human, Adam HaRishon (**אדם** הראשון) and more specifically, because it is a feminine word form, has an allusion to the feminine aspect, the woman who was formed from Adam.

Isaiah 14:14 explains that the name Adam (**אדם**), has an indication of *similar to Heaven* (**אדומה** לעליון). That by observing ourselves (the Microcosmos) carefully, we can understand the system with which G-d established the universe (the Macrocosmos), like is found in Job 19:26.

> ואחר עורי נקפו זאת ומבשרי אחזה אלוה

All of the above preface follows what is found in [Be'er Mayim Chayim to Bereshit 1:26:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Be'er_Mayim_Chaim,_Genesis.1.26.24/he/Be'er_Mayim_Chaim,_Jerusalem_1991.?lang=bi).

> **בצלמנו כדמותנו.** צריך להבין למה בבריאתו לא נאמר כי אם בצלם אלהים עשה אותו ולא נאמר בצלם ודמות אלהים. גם צריך לדעת מהו הצלם ומהו הדמות. ויתכן לומר כי הנה ***עיקר בריאת האדם היה בכדי לְהִדָמוֹת עצמו לבוראו*** ככל אשר יוכל, וכמאמרם בשוחר טוב (מזמור א') חזקיהו ברבי חייא אמר ***אשריהם הצדיקים שמדמין את הצורה ליוצרה*** ואת הנטיעה לנוטעה כו' עד כאן. ואמרו (בבראשית רבה ע"ט, ח') בפסוק (בראשית ל"ג, כ') ויקרא לו אל אלהי ישראל, ***אתה אלוה בעליונים ואני אלוה בתחתונים.*** ולהבינך ענין זה שיקרא אדם אלהים, הוא כי איתא בזוה"ק כמה פעמים (חלק ג', ע"ג.) ***אורייתא וקודשא בריך הוא וישראל חד הוא***, והענין הוא כי ***רמ"ח אברי האדם ושס"ה גידיו הן הן מכוונין לעולם הגדול*** הנקרא בפי החכמים שיעור קומה של יוצר בראשית כמאמר הכתוב (איוב י"ט, כ"ו) ***ומבשרי אחזה אלוה. כי על כן נקרא אדם מבחינת אדמה לעליון*** (ישעיה י"ד, י"ד) כמו שכתב בשל"ה הקדוש ***והוא הציור של כל העולמות שלמעלה ושלמטה בסוד נשמתו וגופו, ונברא ליחד ולקשר כל אבר ואבר מרמ"ח אבריו וכל שס"ה גידיו אל רמ"ח איברים ושס"ה גידים העליונים*** הרמוזים בשיעור קומה הנזכר, ויזכה להיות מרכבה אליהם ואז כאשר יהיה מקושר ומדובק ברמ"ח אברים ושס"ה גידים העליונים אשר הוא מכוון נגדם אז תוכל שיעור קומה עליונה להוריק ולהשפיע אליו כל טוב וברכה כאשר יוכל שאת ***וזה עיקר כיוון הבריאה להיטיב לברואיו***.

With that in mind, the conclusion of the posuk can be considered. The *Tree of Life* and the *Tree of Knowledge*, in contrast to the wholistic aspect of *Tree*, correspond to the inner aspect of the Garden (**בתוך הגן**). They are the inner, driving meaning behind the external aspects of *appearance*.

Looking at the idea of *Tree of Life* and *Tree of Knowledge* as it pertains to the human being can help to understand the *type of tree*.

Surprisingly, these two expressions appear in regard to human anatomy.

The *Tree of Life* is the term used to describe the folds in the inner wall of the uterus ([Arbor Vitae Uterini](https://www.glowm.com/resources/glowm/cd/pages/v1/v1c002.html)).

> A vertical fold is present on the anterior and posterior cervical walls; from these, oblique folds radiate. These folds have been called the arbor vitae uteri or plicae palmatae.

*Tree of Life* also appears in regard to the anatomy of the [human brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbor_vitae_(anatomy)). (Arbor Vitae) It is the inner, white matter of the [Cerebellum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerebellum) which also has a branching, tree-like appearance.

> In humans, the cerebellum plays an important role in motor control, and it may also be involved in some cognitive functions such as attention and language as well as in regulating fear and pleasure responses,[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbor_vitae_(anatomy)) but its movement-related functions are the most solidly established. The human cerebellum does not initiate movement, but contributes to coordination, precision, and accurate timing: it receives input from sensory systems of the spinal cord and from other parts of the brain, and integrates these inputs to fine-tune motor activity.

These two details of human anatomy allude to the underlying, driving concepts behind creation and are the *type of tree*. Discussion of this as it relates to the language in the posuk you cite can be found in Sefer Meorot Natan (מאורת נתן, מערכת ע) [Chapter 11: Eden](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33030&st=&pgnum=131), [Chapter 17: Eitz](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33030&st=&pgnum=132) and [Chapter 34: Oneg](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33030&st=&pgnum=133).

And so what is communicated through this posuk is that the womb, *the source and vehicle of life* and intellect are the *type of the tree* and are the inner driving forces behind G-d's creation.

Comment: _First is that G-d caused the whole of the tree (כל-עץ) to sprout from the earth (האדמה)._ Consider sourcing this understanding. I have not seen any classical commentators who render it suchly.

Comment: @mevaqesh If you want to understand what this is referring to, try looking at the opening chapters of Sefer Shaarei Ohrah by Rabbi Yosef Gikatilla. Specifically what the significance is in Bereshit when using only the name Elokim and then Havayah Elokim, like in this posuk. That second form is what is 'sprouting' from the material earth. It means that we reveal G-d's presence in all things.

Comment: As always this would be a great deal more valuable if you would actually cite sources in the posts.

Comment: Your second comment is arguing on Sefer Be'er Mayim Chayim quoted in the answer. Concerning your first question, see the three links to Meorot Natan at the end of the answer.

Comment: _That by observing ourselves (the Microcosmos) carefully, we can understand the system with which G-d established the universe (the Macrocosmos), like is found in Job 19:26._ I have no idea what this means, but I don't see it in Job. Seeing judgement in the suffering of one's body does not seem equivalent to your claim.

Comment: what are "the Microcosmos" and "the Macrocosmos"?

Comment: Regarding which BMH, link is provided. Regarding your question of What are the Microcosmos, etc. See the paragraph which begins "Isaiah 14:14 explains..."

Comment: You need to more clearly indicate which claims you make are supported by which references you list. The BMH doesn't seem to support the כל עץ interpretation, for example.

Comment: Making up new words in the English language is a horrible way to communicate. If you decide to use strange words, at least link to their definitions.

Comment: @mevaqesh If you are talking about the two terms, 'microcosmos' and 'macrocosmos', I guess you never heard of Carl Sagan. According to the dictionary, they are from the Latin and the Greek. The words have been around for a long time. And the Sheloh quoted in the Be'er Mayim Chayim makes it pretty clear what the idea is.